# Android App in flutter that can tracks total screen ON time

Tags: flutter

I want do build an app in flutter that can track the title time for which the screen is ON, meaning that it would be able to track the total time for which the user was using his/her smartphone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Great that you've got something you want to do, but why did you post it here? SO is for questions and you haven't asked anything. Please [edit] the post to actually ask one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mixin WidgetsBindingObserver to observe the state of the app.

1. Widget

```
class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver
```

2. initState()

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
```

3. dispose()

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
```

4. override didChangeAppLifecycleState()

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {

  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {

  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {

  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {

  }
}
```

5. Check the state and track whether the user is active or not.